# finding elements in a list and return strings - haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi I want to display the names of the dogs that have 0 mins walked for the their second day

```
type Dogs = (String, Float, Float, [Int]) -- Dog,Age,Weight,Time walked daily


testData :: [Dogs]
testData = [("Morris", 5, 8, [0,0,5,8,8,0,0]), 
        ("Tinks", 3, 10, [12,8,15,0,0,0,2]), 
        ("Cash", 6, 11, [0,6,5,0,0,0,3]), 
        ("Lou", 5, 17, [0,2,10,7,8,2,2]),
        ("Kobi", 10, 12, [0,0,8,3,6,7,5]) 
        ("Nala", 7, 8, [8,16,20,3,4,9,2])]
```

So the output would be Morris and Kobi as they have 0 second in the list but I don't know how to go about this, I'm quite new to haskell. I understand that I should use `!! 1` to get the second element out of a list but I don't know how to do this for multiple lists within tuples within a list and then output as string for the names. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Hint: take a look at `filter`.

Comment: Alternatively, a list comprehension: `[dog | dog <- dogs, isSecondDayZero dog]`

Comment: At the beginning don't try to solve the problem with a single function. Think in terms of smaller functions which can be composed. For example you can write a function which given a `Dogs` returns the *time walked in second day*. Given this function  you can use `filter` to select tuples which satisfy a certain condition (`time walked == 0`). Finally you can use `map` to "extract" the names from the resulting list of dogs.

Comment: guide to easy function composition: 1) functions of type `(a->a)` can always be composed with (.), next easiest are functions like `(a->b)` 2) you can always turn `(... -> a -> b)` to `(a -> b)` with currying 3) `map` to change elements of a list or of any `Traversable`, `fold` and friends to turn a list into a single value without explicit loops 4) other helpers like `filter` also exist, but they are more specific and can generally be expressed in terms of map and fold.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I disagree. "Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for anyone that codes to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers ..."

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can create a separate function for determining whether the condition you are looking for is met:

```
isDay2Walked :: Dogs -> Bool
isDay2Walked (_, _, _, (_:x:_)) = x /= 0 -- pattern matching would be more elegant than (!! 1)
isDay2Walked _ = False -- return something if there is no information about the second day
```

Then, use this predicate in a filter over your list, and extract the first element - the name:

```
getDogName :: Dogs -> String
getDogName (name, _, _, _) = name

getDogsNotWalkedOnDay2 :: [Dogs] -> [String]
getDogsNotWalkedOnDay2 = map getDogName . filter (not . isDay2Walked)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you I have tried this but I keep getting a parse error for '=' in the block of code `isDay2Walked (Dogs _ _ _ (_:x:_) = x /= 0 `, I have checked for indentation issues but there isn't any I can see

Comment: @laralouie345 Ah yes, sorry, the Dogs type is a simple type alias for a 4-tuple, and not a 4-argument data constructor, try the edited version

Comment: So this line of code is saying that if x is not zero then it's true that that day has been walked right therefore isDay2Walked would be true but then calling the final function with (not. isDay2Walked) gets the false and searches for the data in the list which determines this instruction? Thank you

Comment: @laralouie345 Yes, by composing the `not` function with our predicate, we filter the list for those elements for which it evaluates to `False`. That means we get those dogs, that were not walked on the second day.

Comment: I got this error with the new version `Couldn't match expected type ‘([Char], Integer, Integer,
                                     [Integer])
                                    -> Dogs’
                  with actual type ‘([Char], Integer, Integer, [Integer])’
    • The function ‘("Kobi", 10, 12, [0, 0, 8, 3, ....])’
      is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘([Char], Integer, Integer, [Integer])’ has none` when I tried to load the module into ghci which is confusing me, have I made an error in the testData?

Comment: @laralouie345 Missing comma on the line with "Kobi"